# Transform function view in Class Based View Django + chartit

Tags: django, function, charts, django-generic-views

I have this function view.

How to transform this function in Class Based View?

In this case i use TemplateView?

```
def linechart(request):
    ds = DataPool(
        series=[{'options': {
            'source': MonthlyWeatherByCity.objects.all()},
            'terms': [
            'month',
            'houston_temp',
            'boston_temp']}
        ])

    cht = Chart(
        datasource=ds,
        series_options=[{'options': {
            'type': 'bar',
            'stacking': False},
            'terms': {
            'month': [
                'boston_temp',
                'houston_temp']
        }}],
        chart_options={'title': {
            'text': 'Weather Data of Boston and Houston'},
            'xAxis': {
            'title': {
                'text': 'Month number'}}})

    return render_to_response('core/linechart.html', {'weatherchart': cht})
```

Return error

[image]

Comment: <joke>one day somebody will kill you for this code-formatting</joke>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'core/linechart.html'

    def get_ds(self):
        return DataPool(...)

    def get_water_chart(self):
        return Chart(datasource=self.get_ds() ...)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyTemplateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['weatherchart'] = self.get_water_chart()

        return context
```

in urls should be something like this

```
url(r'^$', MyTemplateView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Comment: see my github https://github.com/rg3915/chartit/commit/9dd195db3888e20b3fb06b7efd912f2ba2f1aaed

Comment: your get_water_chart doesn't return anything ... add 'return' before 'Chart(' https://github.com/rg3915/chartit/blob/9dd195db3888e20b3fb06b7efd912f2ba2f1aaed/myproject/core/views.py#L38

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution. But pity the chartit not run in Python 3

Comment: save repo to your project and make changes for python 3 (in most cases for small packages it is <= 10 lines of code) then  install this corrected package locally using 'python setup.py install'  ()don't forget remove original one before 'pip uninstall some_package_name') http://python3porting.com/differences.html

Comment: I would prefer use hicharts.js and serialize data manually ... without django-chartit :D ... but you can try port it to python 3

Comment: Can you show me an example of highcharts.js please?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/madzohan/calculateshowfx two years ago, I had little exp in web programming, but  highcharts.js was used

Comment: It is complex hum... :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think your best bet would be to use a generic View instead of a template since it's so easy to make the switch. Something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.views.generic import View

class LinechartView(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ds = DataPool(
        series=[{'options': 
            {'source': MonthlyWeatherByCity.objects.all()},
            'terms': [
                'month',
                'houston_temp',
                'boston_temp']}
        ])

    cht = Chart(
        datasource=ds,
        series_options=[
            {'options': {
                'type': 'bar',
                'stacking': False
            },
            'terms': {
                'month': [
                    'boston_temp',
                    'houston_temp']
        }}],
        chart_options={
            'title': {
                'text': 'Weather Data of Boston and Houston'},
                'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                    'text': 'Month number'
        }}})

    return render(request, {'weatherchart': cht})
  # Doing it like this also allows flexibility to add things like a post easily as well
  # Here's an example of how'd you go about that

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Handles updates of your model object
    other_weather = get_object_or_404(YourModel, slug=kwargs['slug'])
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect("some_template:detail", other_weather.slug)
```

I went ahead and formatted to the best of my abilities trying to view it within stackoverflow. Why not use an IDE like pycharm to make life easy (at least for formatting)?